# Vertica: Convert Bitstrint to integer

Tags: sql, string, binary, vertica

Is there a simple way to convert a binary string to an integer using vertica sql?

something like this:

```
=> SELECT bitstring_to_int('11') as temp
 temp
---
 3
```

I know there is bitstring_to_binary but I can't convert the binary value to an integer either.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `Cast (<value> as int)` ?

Comment: yes, it will just convert the string to an int
so '11' become 11 and NOT 3

Comment: silly me... instead of value you need to put a variable of binary type, or a table's column of a binary type, if you just write it then it will be interpreted as a string not a binary string, for a variable i'm pretty sure it will work, for a column not as certain!

Comment: you mean like this?
`select cast (bitstring_to_binary('11') as int)`
This also won't work

Comment: Well then try this `SELECT BITSTRING_TO_BINARY('11');` i don't have vertica so i can't test anything! there is a function in SQL Server idk if it exists on Vertica too `Convert(,int, <variable/value>)`

Comment: Unfortunatley Vertica has no CONVERT function, or at least I could not find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2023 you can convert binary to int via hex:

```sql
SELECT hex_to_integer(to_hex(bitstring_to_binary('11')))
```

Much shorter than the answer from 2018 (but still not perfect).

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two sollutions (unfortunatly both are not straight forward):
1st: Write a SQL Function, which needs to be expanded depending on the bit length (the Example has 8 bits)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bitstring_to_int(bs VARCHAR)
RETURN INTEGER
AS BEGIN
    RETURN (
        CASE WHEN SUBSTR(RIGHT('0'||bs, 1), 1, 1) = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
        CASE WHEN SUBSTR(RIGHT('0'||bs, 2), 1, 1) = '1' THEN 2 ELSE 0 END + 
        CASE WHEN SUBSTR(RIGHT('0'||bs, 3), 1, 1) = '1' THEN 4 ELSE 0 END + 
        CASE WHEN SUBSTR(RIGHT('0'||bs, 4), 1, 1) = '1' THEN 8 ELSE 0 END + 
        CASE WHEN SUBSTR(RIGHT('0'||bs, 5), 1, 1) = '1' THEN 16 ELSE 0 END + 
        CASE WHEN SUBSTR(RIGHT('0'||bs, 6), 1, 1) = '1' THEN 32 ELSE 0 END + 
        CASE WHEN SUBSTR(RIGHT('0'||bs, 7), 1, 1) = '1' THEN 64 ELSE 0 END + 
        CASE WHEN SUBSTR(RIGHT('0'||bs, 8), 1, 1) = '1' THEN 128 ELSE 0 END 
    ) ;
    END ;
```

Or write a UDF in Python:

```
import vertica_sdk

class bitstring_to_int(vertica_sdk.ScalarFunction):
    def processBlock(self, server_interface, arg_reader, res_writer):
        while(True):
            bs = arg_reader.getString(0)
            res_writer.setInt(sum([int(character) * 2 ** index \
                              for index,character in enumerate(str(bs)[::-1])]))
            res_writer.next()
            if not arg_reader.next():
                break
    def destroy(self, server_interface, col_types):
        pass

class bitstring_to_int_factory(vertica_sdk.ScalarFunctionFactory):
    def createScalarFunction(self, srv):
        return bitstring_to_int()
    def getPrototype(self, srv_interface, arg_types, return_type):
        arg_types.addVarchar()
        return_type.addInt()
    def getReturnType(self, srv_interface, arg_types, return_type):
        return_type.addInt()
```